# How can I update a window's background color with a Tkinter Button

Tags: python, tkinter, background, hex

I am trying to right code that takes a random hexadecimal number, converts it to RGB and shows it in a window.  I also want a button that changes the color.  At the moment, everything works except the button doesn't change the color of the window even though a new Hex number is being generated. I'm trying to open a new window with every press of a button to create an update, no luck. Here is my code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

options = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
r1 =random.choice(options)
r2 =random.choice(options)
r3 =random.choice(options)
r4 =random.choice(options)
r5 =random.choice(options)
r6 =random.choice(options)
hexnumber = '#' +r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 +r5 + r6

def ChangeHex():
    options = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C',  'D', 'E', 'F']
    r1 =random.choice(options)
    r2 =random.choice(options)
    r3 =random.choice(options)
    r4 =random.choice(options)
    r5 =random.choice(options)
    r6 =random.choice(options)
    hexnumber = '#' +r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 +r5 + r6

def New():
    new = tk.Tk()
    new.geometry("800x800")
    new.resizable(0, 0)
    new.configure(bg=hexnumber)
    b = tk.Button(new, text="Change Your Color",command=Combine)
    b.pack()
    new.mainloop()

def ChangeColor():
    root.config(bg = hexnumber)

def Combine():
    ChangeHex()
    ChangeColor()

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")
root.resizable(0, 0)
root.configure(bg=hexnumber)
b = tk.Button(root, text="Change Your Color",command=Combine)
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Also, sorry if this is stupid, this is my first time using tkinter.

Comment: if you create second window then use `Toplevel()` instead of `Tk()` and don't run second `mainloop()`.

Comment: Try first removing the top section of code, setting the `hexnumber` variable. Then add to your `ChangeHex()` function this, `global hexnumber`. This will tell your function to use the global version of `hexnumber`. Also what result did you get when you ran this code?

Answer (score 0):

You have two variables with name `hexnumber`

- first - global - which you create outside functions
- second - local - which you create inside `ChangeHex()`

You have to use `global hexnumber` in `ChangeHex()` to inform function than you want to use external, global variable instead of creating local one

```
def ChangeHex():
    global hexnumber

    options = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C',  'D', 'E', 'F']
    r1 =random.choice(options)
    r2 =random.choice(options)
    r3 =random.choice(options)
    r4 =random.choice(options)
    r5 =random.choice(options)
    r6 =random.choice(options)
    hexnumber = '#' +r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 +r5 + r6
```

But could be better if you use `return hexnumber` and run function with argument - `def ChangeColor(hexnumber):`

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

def ChangeHex():
    options = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C',  'D', 'E', 'F']
    r1 =random.choice(options)
    r2 =random.choice(options)
    r3 =random.choice(options)
    r4 =random.choice(options)
    r5 =random.choice(options)
    r6 =random.choice(options)
    hexnumber = '#' +r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 +r5 + r6
    return hexnumber

def ChangeColor(hexnumber):
    root.config(bg = hexnumber)

def Combine():
    new_hex = ChangeHex()
    ChangeColor(new_hex)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x800")
root.resizable(0, 0)

root.configure(bg=ChangeHex())

b = tk.Button(root, text="Change Your Color",command=Combine)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Also thanks for the global and local variables info, I didn't know that.